# Can I use wildcards in dataset names for PROC CONTENTS?

Tags: sas

On the SAS server we have a library that contains thousands of datasets. I want to catalog the contents of a subset of these, all of which have names that begin with "prov". Can I use a wildcard to specify this?

I tried:

```
PROC CONTENTS DATA=library.prov*;
RUN;
```

But that just produces a log with this error message:

```
ERROR: File LIBRARY.PROV.DATA does not exist.
```

I also tried library.prov%, and that gave the same error.

There are over 100 datasets that start with "prov" so I really don't want to have to do them one at a time. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what information you want that the CONTENTS procedure produces you could just use the DICTIONARY metadata views.

```
proc sql ;
  create table want as 
  select *
  from dictionary.columns
  where libname = 'LIBREF'
    and memname like 'PROV%'
  ;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a WHERE data set option.

```
proc contents data=sashelp._all_ noprint out=class(where=(memname like 'CLASS%'));
   run;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you specify the keyword `_ALL_` in the `PROC CONTENTS` statement, the step displays a list of all the SAS files that are in the specified SAS library.

Example :

```
PROC CONTENTS DATA=libref._ALL_ NODS;
RUN;
```

But to open only the datasets that begin with `prov` you can use the SQL and add `CONTAINS` to `WHERE` e.g:

```
proc sql ;
  create table mytables as
  select *
  from dictionary.tables
  where libname = 'WORK'
  order by memname ;
quit ;
```

Now just run:

```
PROC CONTENTS DATA mytables;
RUN;
```

Comment: That's great, but there are over a thousand datasets in the library, and I only want the contents of the 100 that have names starting with "PROV".

Comment: Would you know which 100 you want , is it based on their last creation date or a naming convention?

Answer (score 0):

I may be using a different version of SAS check if you have the library SASHELP if so try this based on my note in your comment on the previous response you may see that this works out for you:

```
proc sql outobs=100;
create table see as 
select distinct libname,memname,crdate,modate from sashelp.vtable
where libname='LIBRARY' and memname like 'PROV%'
order by memname;
quit;
```